# GTA5-takes me back missions when I load saved data

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-v

So I have got quite far into the game on my Xbox 360 and when I load my recent saved data it will take me back about 2 or 3 missions. I have to repeat the missions again until I get to the same point I was before. But everytime I load it just takes me back to the same missions.

So I started GTA5 from the start. And the saving problem is still happening but now at a different point of the game. I have tried deleting things and restarting but still wont work.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes autosave fails to do the save, have you tried to manually save by sleeping in a bed after completing the missions and then load the game, or if you did save manually have you checked your saved games by using "load game" option to see if there is a save for the missions you completed?

Comment: i always save manualy. I check through my saved games and always go on the recent save.thanks enyway

Comment: Does the most recent save have the name of the mission you completed? I remember when I played Story on 360 I often had the message "saving failed" or the likes so I had to save many times before it actually did save. If this is not the case for you then I don't know how to help.

Comment: I dont say save failed they have always saved and beacsue i started my while game again i have completed the mission where you grab that guy from the AAA and i saved when i completed that and from there its taking me back to the fame and shame mission. When i looked to get up my save from when i had completed the AAA thing it said friends reuinited 31%.thanks enyway

Answer (score 0):

In GTA5 there are many glitches because it is not going to be updated anymore. I had the same problem that you did and it was very frustrating. Just sleep in a bed every time your about to log off, or your done with a mission, so then if the auto save doesn't work, you'll have the manually saved game files.

Comment: GTA V _does_ get updated.

Comment: Gta 5 on the Xbox 360 does not

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured out the problem after you pass the games regular missions the auto save turns off automatically. To fix this, all you have to do is press the pause button to go to the map, and then what you have to do is you have to click right bumper and go over to settings, and then what you have to do which is the last and final step after you were in the settings you have to click a for Xbox or just the bottom button and then you have to go down to the safes are saving or save options depending on what yours says and then all you have to do from there is quick on it and then press on it and it will say off just wish that all you have to do is is just go to the right or the left either way it will fix and then it'll turn autosave back on I figured this out by looking at my screen all my screen said was auto-saving is turned off currently all you have to do to turn it back on is go into settings in change this from saves or savings as I said it did not show up every time but this will guarantee to fix it